# delete functionality not working properly select all checkboxes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

I passed an array of **employee Id** via ajax call in my spring controller.

```
function deleteEntries() {

                var empList = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (_, el) {
                    return $(el).val();
                }).get();

                if (empList.length !== 0) {
                    var r = confirm("Are you sure want to remove multiple entries? \nWarning: This process cannot be undone");
                    if (r === true) {

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'Post',
                            url: baseUrl + 'delete_all',
                            data: {
                                empList: empList

                            },
                            success: function (successMsg) {
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            fail: function (data) {
                                unblockMyScreen();
                                alert('Failed to retrieve data');
                            }
                        });


                    }
                } else
                {
                    alert("Choose atleast single record to delete.");
                }
            }.
```

Now in UI, I have check boxes, also I provide the functionality to delete by selecting all at once and delete.

Now When I select all and press delete button then only single record is going to delete.However, It is working fine without ***select all***

**Here is the delete code**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/delete_all", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean deleteMultipleRecord(@RequestParam(value = "empList[]", required = false) String[] empListToBeRemoved, HttpServletRequest request) {
//        String[] empListToBeRemoved = request.getParameterValues("empList");
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        for (int i = 0; i <= empListToBeRemoved.length; i++) {
            if (!empListToBeRemoved[i].equals("0")) {
                emp.setEmpIdEnc(empListToBeRemoved[i]);
                try {
                    List<OrgStructureTagging> list = orgStructureTaggingDAO.findEmpByProperty("EMP_ID", emp.getEmpId());
                    for (OrgStructureTagging structureTagging : list) {
                        System.out.println("all ids of employees" + structureTagging.getEmployee().getName());
                        orgStructureTaggingDAO.delete(structureTagging);
                    }
                    return true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    log.error("Error Occured While updating the field");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**THIS IS HOW MY JSP CODE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
       <table> 
            <thead>
                 <tr class="">
                   <th width="10%"  >
<label>Select All  <input type="checkbox" id="ckbCheckAll" value="0"> 
</label>
</th>
</thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
<td style="text-align: center">
<label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" value="${tl.employee.empIdEnc}">
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

What I found, a default value of root checkbox  `<label>Select All  <input type="checkbox" id="ckbCheckAll" value="0">` is also passed via array, so I set its default value as `"0"`, so i can easily skip the root checkbox value, but still it become problematic. kindly suggest me the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one record is getting deleted since your method is returning early. To fix this issue, create a boolean variable for returning the method control instead of returning  true/false also decrement 1 from length to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Here is the code snippet that might help you

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete_all", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean deleteMultipleRecord(@RequestParam(value = "empList[]", required = false) String[] empListToBeRemoved, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    for (int i = 0; i <= empListToBeRemoved.length-1; i++) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (!empListToBeRemoved[i].equals("0")) {
            emp.setEmpIdEnc(empListToBeRemoved[i]);
            try {
                List<OrgStructureTagging> list = orgStructureTaggingDAO.findEmpByProperty("EMP_ID", emp.getEmpId());
                for (OrgStructureTagging structureTagging : list) {
                    System.out.println("all ids of employees" + structureTagging.getEmployee().getName());
                    orgStructureTaggingDAO.delete(structureTagging);
                }
                result = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.error("Error Occured While updating the field");
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Imran, it just a silly mistake, I will keep that in mind in future

Comment: Crisp and concise answer ,Thanks